# GridWorld getAdjacentLocation() returning NullPointerException?

Tags: arraylist, nullpointerexception, gridworld

My code can be found here: http://pastebin.com/tmzGgHzi

Basically, what my critter does is it selects a random location and moves to that location, eating all actors in its path. However, the second I click "step", it throws a NullPointerException on line 67. It's something with the getAdjacentLocation() method referencing a null object, but I can't figure it out, and neither can my AP teacher.

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The getLocation() method is returning null.

```
Location loc = this.getLocation();
//Loc is now null, so the following call will result in a null pointer exception
Location newLoc = loc.getAdjacentLocation(getDirection());
```

This is because it's removing itself from the grid/it's eating itself

```
public ArrayList<Actor> getActors(){

    ArrayList<Actor> list = new ArrayList<Actor>();
    Grid<Actor> gr = getGrid();
    Location loc = getLocation();

    atLocation = atRandomLocation();

    if(!atLocation){

        setDirection(loc.getDirectionToward(randomLocation));

        //THIS RETURNS THE CRITTER'S CURRENT LOCATION!
        Actor a = gr.get(getLocation());

        if(a != null)
        //This critter is not going to be null, so it adds it to the list
            list.add(a);

    }else
        getRandomLocation();

    //This list contains all actors to be eaten
    return list;
}
```

*What your method does is check if it's at the location, adds itself to the list, and then EATS ITSELF!*

```
public void processActors(ArrayList<Actor> actors){

    for(Actor a : actors)
        //This list only contains the critter
        a.removeSelfFromGrid();
}
```

What you need to do is find the next location it should move to, eat any actors in that space, and then move in.

P.S. Apparently a Critter will eat itself by default if it's the only actor.